# Application error in Heroku web after deployment

Tags: django, heroku

I have successfully deployed my sentiment analysis web application on Heroku. Most of the features are working properly. One of the features is to extract Twitter data and analyze it. I have set the limit from 1-200 tweets.

Supposedly, this is what the result should be:
[image]

This is in my local host, I can extract up to 200 tweets:
[image]

If I select a smaller number like the system works just fine but the error starts at 71 tweets and above:

[image]

but sometimes, the amount that were successful before then have error if I try it again. Like I tried until 70 and it worked but then I tried 70 again then I get this error

So I try to get the logs.

```
2022-01-09T16:56:37.797892+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.16.8 - - [09/Jan/2022:16:56:37 +0000] "GET /sentiment/import/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3823 "https://sentymeter.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36"
2022-01-09T16:56:37.798990+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sentiment/import/" host=sentymeter.herokuapp.com request_id=3b506434-48cc-4a17-b352-c69b944fce4c fwd="14.192.217.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=4286 protocol=https
2022-01-09T16:56:53.867336+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:324: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfTransformer from version 0.22.2.post1 when using version 1.0.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
2022-01-09T16:56:53.867348+00:00 app[web.1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
2022-01-09T16:56:53.867349+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(
2022-01-09T16:56:54.176512+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:324: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfVectorizer from version 0.22.2.post1 when using version 1.0.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
2022-01-09T16:56:54.176519+00:00 app[web.1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
2022-01-09T16:56:54.176520+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(
2022-01-09T16:56:54.193803+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:324: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from version 0.22.2.post1 when using version 1.0.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
2022-01-09T16:56:54.193805+00:00 app[web.1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
2022-01-09T16:56:54.193806+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(
2022-01-09T16:57:17.642271+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/sentiment/import/" host=sentymeter.herokuapp.com request_id=57a9ee05-9d69-492c-ac18-1d0931c19f84 fwd="14.192.217.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-01-09T16:57:18.349137+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-09 16:57:18 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:43)
2022-01-09T16:57:18.595608+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-09 16:57:18 +0000] [43] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 43)
2022-01-09T16:57:19.324099+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-09 16:57:19 +0000] [80] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 80
2022-01-09T16:57:23.955199+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:324: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfTransformer from version 0.22.2.post1 when using version 1.0.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
2022-01-09T16:57:23.955214+00:00 app[web.1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
2022-01-09T16:57:23.955215+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(
2022-01-09T16:57:24.272549+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:324: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator TfidfVectorizer from version 0.22.2.post1 when using version 1.0.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
2022-01-09T16:57:24.272558+00:00 app[web.1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
2022-01-09T16:57:24.272559+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(
2022-01-09T16:57:24.302387+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:324: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator LogisticRegression from version 0.22.2.post1 when using version 1.0.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk. For more info please refer to:
2022-01-09T16:57:24.302390+00:00 app[web.1]: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#security-maintainability-limitations
2022-01-09T16:57:24.302391+00:00 app[web.1]: warnings.warn(
2022-01-09T16:57:48.296853+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/sentiment/import/" host=sentymeter.herokuapp.com request_id=a67edd34-f815-46b0-8cba-7ea3c777c1ad fwd="14.192.217.156" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-01-09T16:57:48.371626+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-09 16:57:48 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:39)
2022-01-09T16:57:49.398399+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-09 16:57:49 +0000] [4] [WARNING] Worker with pid 39 was terminated due to signal 9
2022-01-09T16:57:49.403030+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-01-09 16:57:49 +0000] [81] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 81
```

It works perfectly in my localhost but it have some issues in heroku.
here's the link to my web app: https://sentymeter.herokuapp.com/
The problem is at import tweets.
Can you help me solve this issue? I cant seem to figure it out.

This is my `sentiment_analysis_code.py`

```
    import os
import re
import nltk
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer 
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import pickle
import itertools
from django.conf import settings
    
  


class sentiment_analysis_code():

    lem = WordNetLemmatizer()

    def cleaning(self, text):
        txt = str(text)
        txt = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", txt)
        if len(txt) == 0:
            return 'no text'
        else:
            txt = txt.split()
            index = 0
            for j in range(len(txt)):
                if txt[j][0] == '@':
                    index = j
            txt = np.delete(txt, index)
            if len(txt) == 0:
                return 'no text'
            else:
                words = txt[0]
                for k in range(len(txt)-1):
                    words+= " " + txt[k+1]
                txt = words
                txt = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', txt)
                if len(txt) == 0:
                    return 'no text'
                else:
                    txt = ''.join(''.join(s)[:2] for _, s in itertools.groupby(txt))
                    txt = txt.replace("'", "")
                    txt = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(txt)
                    #data.content[i] = [w for w in data.content[i] if not w in stopset]
                    for j in range(len(txt)):
                        txt[j] = self.lem.lemmatize(txt[j], "v")
                    if len(txt) == 0:
                        return 'no text'
                    else:
                        return txt

    def get_tweet_sentiment(self, tweet):
 
        tweet_in_pandas = pd.Series(' '.join(self.cleaning(tweet)))

        path_vec = os.path.join(settings.MODELS, 'vectoriser-ngram-(1,2).pickle')
        path_model = os.path.join(settings.MODELS, 'Sentiment-LR.pickle')

        # load vectorizer
        # vec_file = 'vectoriser-ngram-(1,2).pickle'
        vectorizer = pickle.load(open(path_vec, 'rb'))

        # load trained model
        # filename = 'Sentiment-LR.pickle'
        model = pickle.load(open(path_model, 'rb'))

        test = vectorizer.transform(tweet_in_pandas)
        predicted_sentiment = model.predict(test)
        final_sentiment = (predicted_sentiment[0])
        if final_sentiment == 'positive':
            return 'Positive'
        elif final_sentiment == 'neutral':
            return 'Neutral'
        elif final_sentiment == 'negative':
            return 'Negative'
```

This is my HTML for the sentiment/import page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}

<head>
  <title>Sentymeter: Import Tweets</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--Chart js-->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-Uv9BNBucvCPipKQ2NS9wYpJmi8DTOEfTA/nH2aoJALw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.css"
    integrity="sha256-aa0xaJgmK/X74WM224KMQeNQC2xYKwlAt08oZqjeF0E=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <title>Import Tweets</title>
</head>

<body>

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container pt-5">
      <div class="row justify-content-lg-center">
        <h1>Import Tweets Result</h1>
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-12 mb-4">
          <div class="bg-white">

            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between px-3">
                  <h5><strong>Keyword: </strong>{{ handle }}</h5>
                  <h5><strong>Positive: </strong>{{ pos }}</h5>
                  <h5><strong>Neutral: </strong>{{ neu }}</h5>
                  <h5><strong>Negative: </strong>{{ neg }}</h5>
                  <h5><strong>Total Tweets: </strong>{{ number }}</h5>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br>

      <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
            <script>
              const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
              const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'pie',
                data: {
                  labels: ['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative'],
                  // labels: ['{{pos}}','{{neu}}','{{neg}}', ] ,
                  datasets: [{
                    label: 'Counts',
                    data: [{{ pos }}, {{ neu }},{{ neg }} ,],

              backgroundColor: [
                'green',
                'orange',
                'red',
              ],
                                }]
                            },
              options: {
                scales: {
                  y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                  }
                }
              }
                        });
            </script>

          </div>

          <div class="col">
            <canvas id="myChart1" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
            <script>
              const ctx1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');
              const myChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: {
                  labels: ['Positive', 'Neutral', 'Negative'],
                  datasets: [{
                    label: 'Counts',
                    data: [{{ pos }}, {{ neu }},{{ neg }} ,],
              backgroundColor: [
                'green',
                'orange',
                'red',
              ],

                borderWidth: 1
                                }]
                                    },
              options: {
                scales: {
                  yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                      beginAtZero: true
                    }
                  }]
                }
              }
                                });
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row justify-content-lg-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary"><a href="/sentiment/import">
          <h7 class="white-text" color=white;>New Search</h7>
        </a></button>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div class="tbl-header mx-5">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Tweet</th>
          <th>Sentiment</th>
          <th>Emotag</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
          {% for i,j in list_of_tweets_and_sentiments %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{i}}</td>
            <td>{{j}}</td>
            {% if j == 'Negative' %}
            <td><img src="{% static 'icons/negative.png' %}"></td>
            {% endif %}
            {% if j == 'Positive' %}
            <td><img src="{% static 'icons/positive.png' %}"></td>
            {% endif %}
            {% if j == 'Neutral' %}
            <td><img src="{% static 'icons/neutral.png' %}"></td>
            {% endif %}
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <br><br>




    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like a timeout, possibly related to those pickle warnings. What code is supposed to handle posts to `/sentiment/import/`? And what are you trying to unpickle?

Comment: my sentiment prediction model and vectorizer.

Comment: I have uploaded my code related to the pickle file here. Can you have a look at it? but the thing is, it works just fine in my local host so could it be an issue with deploying it with heroku?